# How to sort an object using array of objects

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
let object = {
  'demo@gmail.com': [
    {
      a: 5,
      name: demo
    },
    {
      a: 4,
      name: demo
    }
  ],
  'demo1@gmail.com': [
    {
      a:2 ,
      name: demo1
    },
    {
      a: 1,
      name: demo1
    }
  ]

}
```

Expected output:

I am trying to write an function to sort an object like this

But i found it is difficult.can anyone can give me some hints to write such function? i need it to show the grouped messages

```
let object = {
  'demo1@gmail.com': [
    {
      a:2 ,
      name: demo1
    },
    {
      a: 1,
      name: demo1
    }
  ],
  'demo@gmail.com': [
    {
      a: 5,
      name: demo
    },
    {
      a: 4,
      name: demo
    }
  ],


}
```

Comment: what is the logic of the sort? is it the `a` value? which `a` value is used, the first or the second, or the lowest of the two or the highest of the two

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values

Comment: Actually, I just re-read the object, you're correct!! object properties have no order (not quite true, there is a way to get the order you want, but ... really, why!!!

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, especially when you read NickFitz answer to the proposed dupe (I couldn't vtc for that because I already vtc'd as needs detail)

Comment: @Nick - vtc'd with the dupe :p

Comment: @JaromandaX an excellent result all round! :-)

Comment: @JaromandaX  {
  "demo@gmailc.cm": [
    {
      "session_id": 0,
      "timestamp": 1599531505
    },
    {
      "session_id": 0,
      "timestamp": 1599532249
    }
    ],
  "demo2@email.cm": [
    {
      "session_id": 0,
      "timestamp": 1599705548
    },
    {
      "session_id": 0,
      "timestamp": 1599705557
    }]
}

Comment: @JaromandaX the order of object to be sorted by latest timestamp

Comment: there is no timestamp in you example object

Comment: please refer to my above comment i've shared you another json @JaromandaX

Comment: sorry, I don't read code in comments